# How do I center a DIV with no parent?

Tags: html, css, center, text-align

I want to center my form in the center of teh horizontal row it is in.  I thought this would be as simple as

```
#control {
    text-align: center;
}
```

The element I want to center is

```
<div id="control" class="btn">
    <div id="btn_container"><img width="100" height="100" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/minecraft-icons/512/Stone_Pickaxe.png" alt="Mining pick" /></div>
    <span>Start</span> 
</div>
```

However, the element is still not being centered -- https://jsfiddle.net/xwdnvcy5/58/ .  I'm not getting something really obvious, but I can't tell what it is.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't match your question code at all.  Yopiv

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one is not very intuitive, but try setting the margin to `0 auto`.

```
#control {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why I am getting down votes, checked it in the above jsfiddle and guess what.  It works.

Comment: If I had to guess I think you got the downvote for not formatting the question correctly? I gave you an upvote though because the answer was technically correct, just little effort.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple actually. You need to set the margin-left/right as `auto`.. like this:

```
#control {
        margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you try to center the #control div? 
Try this

```
#control {
  position:relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: This works but is unnecessarily complicated I think, a simple `margin: 0 auto` works fine for this sort of thing.

Comment: I guess in his case it works, since he has another .btn class and it has display: table; also not sure why .btn has text-align: left, then #control has text-algin:center